# How to populate Imagelist dynamically (data from database) C#

Tags: c#

I need to populate an `ImageList` dynamically. Means I stored `image names` in a database table. But images are in categories folder inside project folder `(1.jpg, 2.jpg...)` using a `while` loop I tried to add image into `ImageList` and bind to the `ListView`.

Here is my code and TABLE. No errors but images are not loading. I am not sure image path is correct or not. What is wrong with my code and how to do that?

```
public void show()
{
    ImageList imgs = new ImageList();
    imgs.ImageSize = new Size(50,50);

    MySqlConnection con = cn.connection();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM categories";
    MySqlDataReader rd;
    con.Open();
    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rd.Read())
    {
        try
        {
            imgs.Images.Add(Image.FromFile("./categories/" + rd.GetString(2)));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
    listView1.SmallImageList = imgs;
    while (rd.Read())
    {
        listView1.Items.Add("asas",rd.GetString(0));
    }
}
```

TABLE

[image]

IMAGE PATH

```
C:\vb\nishantha\pos3\categories
```

PROJECT FOLDER

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyanM.jpg)

IMAGE FOLDER

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcCvA.jpg)

Comment: You mentioned as **category** folder, but in the code I see categories. Can you just open the link of the image using inspect element in the browser?

Comment: yes it should be categories .. file:///C:/vb/nishantha/pos3/categories/1.jpg

Comment: Can you inspect the url link of the image using browser? So you get to know from where it is trying to pull the image.

Comment: what do you mean by inspect the url .. this is C# application...neh.

Comment: I mean can you open the application in a browser?

Comment: so where is the project located? `C:\vb\nishantha\pos3` --is this the  location of the project ?

Comment: @JS_GodBlessAll YES

Comment: Also is this an asp.net application?

Comment: @JS_GodBlessAll  NO it is desktop one

Comment: Better, try putting  a break point here `(Image.FromFile("./categories/" + rd.GetString(2)))` and check the path you are getting.

Comment: okay what is the control that you are using to bind the image to ? A picture control or what? you have to ensure you are setting the right property  as the source?

Comment: This type of question should not be asked here but worked out with the debugger!

Comment: anyway if you can pls help... coz Im stuck with this.

Comment: Did you even tried to put a break point and check what you are getting ?

Comment: what do you mean by `break point` can you explain it bit...pls

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
imgs.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("\\categories\\" + rd.GetString(2)));
```

might help you achieve it And the next `while` loop might be a problem since running the first loop already read all the records from the DB. So if you want you can include the same in the first loop itself.

```
listViewItem lvi = new listViewItem();
while (rd.Read())
{
    try
    {
        imgs.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("\\categories\\" + rd.GetString(2)));
        lvi.SubItems.Add(rd.GetString(0));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}
listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
listView1.SmallImageList = imgs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure categories folder with files is available in root directory.

e.g. if you are building the application in  debug mode, then categories folder and files should be in ~/debug/categories/..jpg. for doing this take below steps:

Expand categories folder, select all files --> Right click --> Property --> CopyToOutputDirectory to Copy always.

Finally in last line for adding the items in the listview change the below code:

```
while (rd.Read())
{
   listView1.Items.Add("asas",rd.GetString(0));
}
```

To

```
for (int j = 0; j < imgs.Images.Count; j++)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
    item.ImageIndex = j;
    item.Text = "asdf";

    this.listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: to call `Path` what should I include.. because it is showing an error `not in current context`

Comment: Okay. then use the same code you have written to add the image in image list e.g. imgs.Images.Add(Image.FromFile("./categories/" + rd.GetString(2)));

Comment: And select all images in categories folder --> Right click --> Property --> CopyToOutputDirectory  of Copy always.

Comment: `imgs.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(".\categories\" + rd.GetString(2))); ` showing an error  so I put `mgs.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(".\\categories\\" + rd.GetString(2))); ` but both not working..

Comment: Are you getting any exception? or just not able to see the images in listbox control?